# Game Engine - Getting depth map

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine, image

Would someone let me know how I can get the depth map for each frame of my rendered animation? By depth map, I mean an image that shows the distance of each point on objects from the camera.

It seems there are some ways using Node Editor, but I have to do that completely with python scripting.

Comment: By depth map you mean zdepth pass of the render engine?

Comment: That's right. For example, the objects closer to the camera should be brighter than the objects far from the camera.

Comment: Cycles or BI? You only have to enable the pass to get it. Which process you want to automate?

Comment: I am new to blender. I am not sure about the difference between Cycles and BI. I meant the zdepth for animation that BGE produces.

Comment: I think *poor* meant what render engine you are using, you can see it at the top of the window

Comment: Please add more information/context to your question and try to explain what do you exactly want to achieve in order to get a solid answer.

Comment: I have created an animation (for example, a ball moving on a surface) with "Game Logic" using "Blender Game". Now, I want to get the zdepth for each frame of the animation and save it. I don't want to use Blender Rendered and I want to use only Blender Game. Does this clarify my question?